# why querySelectorAll is not a function error pop up when i change the text of a tag using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change the text of a tag using javascript.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="btn_list03 btn_list">
    <a href="javascirpt:void(0);" id="btn_sort">good</a>
</div>
```

This is my JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector('#btn_sort').textContent = "comment"
$('#btn_sort').text("comment");
```

I've tried these code. they change the text well but every single time i change the text i get this error querySelectorAll is not a function.

Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: c.querySelectorAll is not a function
>           at MutationObserver.

Should i just ignore that error or Did i make something wrong?

any help would be appreciate thank you.

--edited--

```
n && c && e.MutationObserver && (o = new e.MutationObserver(function(e) {
                                for (var t = [], n = 0; n < e.length; n += 1) {
                                    var o = e[n];
                                    if ("attributes" === o.type)
                                        t.push(o.target);
                                    else if ("childList" === o.type)
                                        for (var r = o.addedNodes, i = 0; i < r.length; i += 1) {
                                            var c = r[i];
                                            t.push(c);
                                            for (var s = c.querySelectorAll("[id],[class],[href]"), a = 0; a < s.length; a += 1)
                                                t.push(s[a])
                                        }
                                }
                                l(t)
                            }
```

i found it this error is occurred in external js library and this is where the error is occurred.

Comment: I find it strange that you're getting an error with `querySelectorAll` when you're not even using it in your js?

Comment: yes, that's all what i wrote

Comment: Is that all your JS code? It's talking about a MutationObserver but you don't use that in your code? When the error occurs you can see what file it occurred in by looking at the file name to the far right of the error message. Make sure the error is occurring in your js file and not an external library

Comment: ahhh i found where this error is occurring

Comment: Where was it out of curiosity? It may help future readers

Comment: what's content_script_bundle.js?? it's the name of js file

Comment: If its an external library you can most likely ignore the message - you shouldn't have to dive into someone else's code just to fix an error like this (might be worth looking at a different library). If you didn't link `content_script_bundle.js` in your HTML file then it's most likely an error with a browser extension (or a tamper monkey script if you have that extension installed)

Comment: Do you have Ghostery extension installed? I found out that pausing it made the errors disappear.

Comment: @balsimpson yes it is! This should be deepened by someone to give a final answer

Comment: @balsimpson wow! yes i have installed that extension. as you said i turned it off and the error is disappeared. Thank you a lot thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was caused from chrome's Ghostery extension not my js problem.

when i turned it off the error was disappeared.

Comment: You should probably open an issue on this extension, because indeed assuming that all the Nodes in MutationRecord.addedNodes will be Element is an issue, as your case demonstrated.